# TSQL pivot a single column table

Tags: t-sql, pivot

Sorry for the late response I was off for few days, and for not specifying the exact table structure. Please ignore the previous description above. I have more information so my original question is not any longer valid as I obtain more information regarding what I really need as described below:

I have the following table (simplified version for the sake of discussion). First line is the headers:

```
VariableID  DocumentID  Revision  Value
44          12          2         Val1
45          12          2         Val2
45          12          3         Val3
44          13          1         Val4
46          13          2         Val5
47          14          1         Val6
```

I’d like to convert it (assuming n number of rows) to the following grouped by (DocumentId, revision) table:

```
Documentid  revision  variable1 (44)  variable2 (45)  variable3(46)  variable(47)  variable (n)
12          2         Val1            Val2            null           null
12          3         null            Val3            null           null
13          1         Val4            null            null           null
13          2         null            null            Val5           null
14          1         null            null            null           Val6
```

Number of variable will be retrieved dynamically. I do not know how many variable will be in source table as input.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide a lot of details about your current table structure or sample data.  So I will provide you with some samples of the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function that will perform this.

There are two options for PIVOT, a Static if you know the number of columns to transform or a Dynamic which will get the list of columns at run-time to transform.

EDIT: 
Based on the change to your question, you can still perform a PIVOT

A Static Pivot would look like this ([Sql Fiddle sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b08e/1)):

```
select *
from 
(
  select *
  from t
) x
pivot 
(
  max(value)
  for variableid in([44], [45], [46], [47])
) p
```

As Dynamic Pivot looks like this ([Sql Fiddle Sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b08e/11)):

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsAlias AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(variableid) 
                    from t
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SELECT @colsAlias = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(m.variableid) + ' AS ' + QUOTENAME('variable' + cast(n.variableid as varchar(10)))  
    FROM t m INNER JOIN t n ON m.variableid = n.variableid
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT documentid, revision, ' + @colsAlias + ' from 
             (
                select *
                from t
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for variableid in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Comment: thank you. I posted a new description of my question in the original post however I am unable to tabulate the data so it may be difficult to read.

Comment: @user1491749 please see my edit, you can still use a PIVOT to get the data in the format you want.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the dynamic pivot. I get the following error. Is this an escape issue? if so how do I escape the respective column? Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'variable47'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'variable47'.

Comment: Can you create a SQL fiddle with the code you are running? Then post the link.

Comment: OK I got it. I changed the size of the @query to 256 from max and it trimmed the select statement. I think I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

The PIVOT operator sounds like it is what you are looking for, it is available in both Microsoft SQL Server and Microsoft Access, I'm not sure if it is available in Sybase though. Here is the MSDN article on it: [T-SQL Pivot Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)